Amp script claim row is claiming same row twice
I'm running into a weird case where the claimrow function is claiming the same row for multiple users. What I am trying to do is prevent a user from receiving an email if he/she already received a coupon. In the below code, multiple users are receiving the same code. Anyone has an idea on how to change this?
%%[ 
   var @SubscriberKey, @Email, @defaultCoupon, @claimedbefore, @rows, @rowCount
   set @SubscriberKey = attributevalue("SubscriberKey")
   set @Email = attributevalue("Email")
   set @rows = LookupRows("ent.vouchers","SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)
set @defaultCoupon = "Er is geen code beschikbaar. Neem contact op met onze klantenservice." 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount == 0 then

    if _messagecontext == "PREVIEW" then 
        set @couponCode = "XX PREVIEWMAIL XX" 
    else 
   
   set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("ENT.vouchers", "CouponCode", "IsClaimed", @defaultCoupon, "Email", @Email, "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)
endif

 /*function inserts email into data extention used for exclusion 2 years*/
  InsertDE(
    "ent.exclusion_list",
    "Email",
    @Email,
    "SubscriberKey",
    @SubscriberKey,
    "CouponCode",
    @couponCode
  )

else
RaiseError("User already claimed code", True)
EndIf
]%%’


As you are describing how you can claim coupon codes, but that you are claiming the same code for different subscribers, I suggest you to try to replace the ClaimRowValue() function with a combination of LookupOrderedRows(), if, and UpdateDE(). This will look for rows in ent.vouchers with isClaimed = 'false' and update based on CouponCode.
%%[ 
   var @SubscriberKey, @Email, @defaultCoupon, @claimedbefore, @rows, @rowCount
   set @SubscriberKey = attributevalue("SubscriberKey")
   set @Email = attributevalue("Email")
   set @rows = LookupRows("ent.vouchers","SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)
set @defaultCoupon = "Er is geen code beschikbaar. Neem contact op met onze klantenservice." 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount == 0 then

    if _messagecontext == "PREVIEW" then 
        set @couponCode = "XX PREVIEWMAIL XX" 
    else 
    /* Lookup first row with a couponCode that has not been claimed yet. Use this code and update the row with UpdateDE(). Handle default logic with an if */
    set @claimRows = LookupOrderedRows("ent.vouchers", 1, "CouponCode asc", "IsClaimed", "false")
    set @claimRowCount = rowcount(@claimRows)
      if @claimRowCount > 0 then
      set @claimRow = row(@claimRows, 1)
      set @couponCode = field(@claimRow, "CouponCode")
      UpdateDE("ent.vouchers", "CouponCode", @couponCode, "IsClaimed", "true", "Email", @Email, "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)
      else
      set @couponCode = @defaultCoupon
      endif
    endif

 /*function inserts email into data extention used for exclusion 2 years*/
  InsertDE(
    "ent.exclusion_list",
    "Email",
    @Email,
    "SubscriberKey",
    @SubscriberKey,
    "CouponCode",
    @couponCode
  )

else
RaiseError("User already claimed code", True)
EndIf
]%%

